# Rails sitemap generator, undefined method post_path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, path, rubygems, sitemap

I am using the following gem:

https://github.com/kjvarga/sitemap_generator

I have a posts model and have used post_path(post) in other parts of the application as it is based on Enki.

However in the sitemap file:

```
Post.all.each do |post|
    sitemap.add post_path(post), :lastmod => post.updated_at
  end
```

This returns the error when running the rake task  rake sitemap:refresh:

```
rake aborted!
undefined method `post_path' for #<SitemapGenerator::Interpreter:0x279efd0>
```

And:

```
Post.all.each do |post|
  sitemap.add posts_path(post), :lastmod => post.updated_at
end
```

Returns no errors. Can anyone shed any light on this or do I need to provide more of the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sitemap_generator` actually includes all the helper methods in the `create` block, so you *should* be able to access `posts_path`.

I had a similar problem, and my answer also made me feel stupid. I was storing `sitemap.rb` in `config/initializers`, when it should be stored in the `config/` directory. That meant it was running on startup and failing because the url helpers weren't properly loaded (and, incidentally, when I called `rake sitemap:refresh`, the sitemap was being generated *twice* - once in the initializer and again as the rake task!)

Comment: Moving sitemap.rb to config/sitemap.rb is exactly the right thing here.

Answer (score 0):

I feel a bit stupid on this one, it was simply because post_path was a helper and not accessible, so I simply had to move it into the method directly.

Comment: This is not the correct answer.  The route helpers absolutely should be available to you.  check the next answer, which is probably the root of the issue.  duplicating an existing method is not the greatest of ideas.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I have now accepted the above answer as being correct.